# Calculate the number of representations of a number as a sum of fibonacci numbers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, fibonacci

My group struggled to find a good algorithm but all we could come up with was an exponential one. Is there a way to make it faster? Here's the full question:

> Define a function
>
> ```
> function F(n:Integer):Integer;
> ```
>
> which will calculate the number of different representations of a non-negative number n as a sum of Fibonacci numbers with non-equal, positive indexes. For example (Fib(k) means the k-th Fibonacci number):
>
> F(0)=0
>
> F(1)=2, because 1=Fib(1)=Fib(2)
>
> F(2)=2, because 2=Fib(3)=Fib(1)+Fib(2)
>
> F(3)=3, because 3=Fib(4)=Fib(3)+Fib(1)=Fib(3)+Fib(2)
>
> and so on

I think that the first, inevitable step is making an array of *n* Fibonacci numbers, something like this:

```
Fib[1]:=1;
Fib[2]:=1;
for i:=3 to n do
    Fib[i]:=Fib[i-1]+Fib[i-2];
```

Of course, we could optimise it by calculating only those Fibonacci numbers that are smaller than or equal to *n*, but this wouldn't help much, since dynamic arrays were not allowed, anyway. So how can we proceed to avoid exponential time complexity?

Comment: I would say F(0) = 1 (the empty sum)

Comment: The cheating (but still quite educational) approach is to figure out the answer for the first 15 or so integers and then look the sequence up in the online encyclopedia of integer sequences.  For this particular case, that gives https://oeis.org/A000121.  I agree with @NiklasB. about `F(0)`, by the way: `0` is expressible as the empty sum.

Comment: @MarkDickinson the maple and prolog code given there to compute the polynomial coefficient which gives the answer is exponential time in terms of log(n), the input size.

Comment: @user2566092: Yes, true.  It's even exponential space, since you end up with a (non-sparse) power series with `O(n)` terms as an intermediate result.  (What prolog, by the way? I only see Maple and GP/Pari.)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Wow, that's about as explicit as it can possibly get :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's prove some stuff about numbers:

**Lemma 1**: Let *n ≥ 1* be an integer and *Fib(i)* be the largest Fibonacci number with *Fib(i) ≤ n*. Then in a representation of *n* as a sum of Fibonacci numbers with distinct indices, either *Fib(i)* or *Fib(i - 1)* appears, but not both.

*Proof:* We can show by induction that the sum *Fib(1) + Fib(2) + ... + Fib(i - 2) = Fib(i) - 1*. Since *Fib(i) < n*, we need at least *Fib(i - 1)* or *Fib(i)* in the representation. But not both, since *Fib(i) + Fib(i - 1) = Fib(i + 1) > n* (otherwise *Fib(i)* would not be the maximal Fibonacci number smaller than or equal to *n*).

**Lemma 2**: *n - Fib(i) < Fib(i - 1)* and *n - Fib(i - 1) < Fib(i)*.

*Proof:* Those are easy to show. Left as an exercise to the reader.

I initially thought that this gives rise to the recurrence *F(n) = F(n - Fib(i)) + F(n - Fib(i - 1))*, but there is a catch: It could be that *n - Fib(i - 1) ≥ Fib(i - 1)*, so in that case it can happen that *F(i - 1)* is reused, which we disallowed. We can fix that quite easily, though: We can just give the function *F* an additional boolean flag that tells it to disallow the recursion into *F(n - Fib(i))*.

One last problem remains: How to compute *i*? One important observation is that Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially, so we have *i = O(log n)*. We can just use brute force to find it (compute all Fibonacci numbers up to *n*:

```
function F(n : Integer, recurseHigh = True: Bool):
    if n == 0: return 1
    a, b = 1, 1
    while a + b <= n:
        a, b = b, a + b
    res = 0
    if recurseHigh: res += F(n - b)
    res += F(n - a, n - a < a)
    return res
```

It happens to work fast enough even with this "stupid" implementation for 32-bit integers. If you use memoization, it sure works even for much bigger numbers, but then you need dynamically allocated memory.

I have not yet proven the runtime complexity of this, but it sure is damn fast if memoization is used. I think it's *O(log² n)* additions and would be *O(log n * log log n)* if we precompute the Fibonacci numbers up to *n* and do a binary search for *i*. Not sure about the case without memoization though, it doesn't seem to work well with *n* beyond 2³².

Here are some values of *F* in case you're interested, computed with a memoized version of the above function in Python:

```
F(0) = 1
F(1) = 2
F(2) = 2
F(3) = 3
F(4) = 3
F(5) = 3
F(6) = 4
F(7) = 3
F(8) = 4
F(9) = 5
F(10) = 4
F(11) = 5
F(12) = 4
F(13) = 4
F(14) = 6
F(4079078553298575003715036404948112232583483826150114126141906775660304738681982981114711241662261246) = 70875138187634460005150866420231716864000000
F(2093397132298013861818922996230028521104292633652443820564201469339117288431349400794759495467500744) = 157806495228764859558469497848542003200000000
F(1832962638825344364456510906608935117588449684478844475703210731222814604429713055795735059447061144) = 9556121706647393773891318116777984000000000
F(6529981124822323555642594388843027053160471595955101601272729237158412478312608142562647329142961542) = 7311968902691913059222356326906593280000000
F(3031139617090050615428607946661983338146903521304736547757088122017649742323928728412275969860093980) = 16200410965370556030391586130218188800000000
F(4787808019310723702107647550328703908551674469886971208491257565640200610624347175457519382346088080) = 7986384770542363809305167745746206720000000
F(568279248853026201557238405432647353484815906567776936304155013089292340520978607228915696160572347) = 213144111166298008572590523452227584000000000
F(7953857553962936439961076971832463917976466235413432258794084414322612186613216541515131230793180511) = 276031486797406622817346654015856836608000000
F(2724019577196318260962320594925520373472226823978772590344943295935004764155341943491062476123088637) = 155006702456719127405700915456167116800000000
F(4922026488474420417379924107498371752969733346340977075329964125801364261449011746275640792914985997) = 3611539307706585535227777776416785118003200
F(10^1000) = 1726698225267318906119107341755992908460082681412498622901372213247990324071889761112794235130300620075124162289430696248595221333809537338231776141120533748424614771724793270540367766223552120024230917898667149630483676495477354911576060816395737762381023625725682073094801703249961941588546705389069111632315001874553269267034143125999981126056382866927910912000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

We observe that it seems like *F(n) = Θ(sqrt(n))*, another result that I haven't yet proven.

**UPDATE:** Here's the Python code:

```
memo = {}
def F(n, x=True):
    if n == 0: return 1
    if (n, x) in memo: return memo[n,x]
    i = 1
    a, b = 1, 1
    while b + a <= n:
        a, b = b, a + b
    memo[n,x] = (F(n - b) if x else 0) + F(n - a, n - a < a)
    return memo[n,x]
```

**UPDATE 2**: You can get better runtime even without memoization by using binary search to find *i* and computing *Fib(i)* using fast matrix exponentiation. Probably not worth the effort though, especially not for 32-bit n.

**UPDATE 3**: Just for fun, here is an implementation that provably does only `O(log n)` additions:

```
fib = [0,1]
def greedy(n):
    while fib[-1] < n:
        fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])
    i = 1
    while fib[i+1] <= n: i += 1
    digs = set()
    while n:
        while fib[i] > n: i -= 1
        digs.add(i)
        n -= fib[i]
    return digs

def F(n):
    digs = greedy(n)
    top = max(digs)
    dp = [[[0,0,0] for _ in xrange(4)] for _ in xrange(top+1)]
    for j in xrange(0, 2): dp[0][j][0] = 1
    for i in xrange(1, top + 1):
        for j in xrange(0,2):
            for k in xrange(0,j+1):
                if i in digs:
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[i-1][k+j][j] + dp[i-1][k+j+1][j+1]
                else:
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[i-1][k+j][j] + dp[i-1][k+j-1][j-1]
    return dp[top][0][0]
```

It first finds a greedy representation of the number in the fibonacci base and then uses DP to find the number of ways to carry over digits in that representation to build up the final number. `dp[i,j,k]` is the number of ways to represent the prefix `1..i` of the number in fibonacci base if we have carry `j` onto position `i` and carry `k` onto position `i - 1`. Using this, we can compute `F(10^50000)` in under 5 seconds (the result has more than 20000 decimal digits!)

Comment: The trailing zeros on those `F` values are suspicious. Is there some rounding going on somewhere?

Comment: @Mark: No, Python has bigints, all the computations are exact. It's in fact not too surprising that the powers of 2 and 5 are quite high. The distribution of prime factors seems to be somewhat exponentially decreasing from low prime factors to higher ones.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that Python has bigints. :-)  If those output numbers are correct (and after some experimentation I believe they are), the results are very interesting:  when I factorize any one of those, I always get relatively small prime factors.

Comment: @Marc: I added the Python source code, it doesn't use floating point. Yes, I see an exponential decrease in prime exponents (`exp(2) ~ 2*exp(3) ~ 2*exp(5)` etc.), whatever that means.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm going to stay awake for half the night trying to figure out where all the small prime factors come from...

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Please don't forget to tell me when you're done ;)

Comment: Fascinating answer and comments by @MarkDickinson. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: @NiklasB. I have discovered a truly marvellous solution, which this comment box is too small to contain. :-) (With apologies to Fermat.)  I've posted the explanation in an answer.

Comment: @Mark: Haha, nice job :) And there I thought you had given up on the problem

Comment: @NiklasB. just a nit pick ,                                                                                                 "It could be that n - Fib(i - 1) ≥ Fib(i - 1), so in that case it can happen that F(i - 1) is" , here instead of  "F(i-1)" it should be Fib(i-1)... which means we are disallowing the usage of same fibonacci numbers more than once.. Also it would have been better if you could have given an explanation on Time Complexities...

Answer (score 5):

I was intrigued by two aspects of [Niklas B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916657/niklas-b)'s answer: the speed of the computation (even for huge numbers), and the tendency of the results to have small prime factors.  These hint that the solution can be computed as a product of small terms, and that indeed turns out to be the case.

To explain what's going on, I need some notation and terminology.  For any nonnegative integer `n`, I'll define the (unique) **greedy representation** of `n` to be the sum of Fibonacci numbers obtained by repeatedly taking the largest Fibonacci number not exceeding `n`.  So for example, the greedy representation of `10` is `8 + 2`.  It's easy to observe that we never use `Fib(1)` in such a greedy representation.

I also want a compact way to write these representations, and for that I'm going to use bitstrings.  Much like binary, except that the place values follow the Fibonacci sequence instead of the sequence of powers of 2, and I'll write with the least significant digit first.  So for example `00100001` has `1`s in position `2` and position `7`, so represents `Fib(2) + Fib(7) = 1 + 13 = 14`.  (Yes, I'm starting counting at `0`, and following the usual convention that `Fib(0) = 0`.)

A brute force way of finding all representations is to start with the greedy representation and then explore all possibilities for rewriting a subpattern of the form `001` as a pattern of the form `110`;  i.e., replacing `Fib(k+2)` with `Fib(k) + Fib(k+1)` for some `k`.

So we can always write the greedy representation of `n` as a bitstring, and that bitstring will be a sequence of `0`s and `1`s, with no two adjacent `1`s.  Now the key observation is that we can partition this bitstring into pieces and compute the number of rewrites for each separate piece, multiplying to get the total number of representations.  This works because certain subpatterns in the bitstring prevent interaction between the rewrite rules for the portion of the string to the left of the pattern, and those to the right.

For an example, let's look at `n = 78`.  Its greedy representation is `00010000101`, and a brute-force approach quickly identifies the full set of representations.  There are ten of them:

```
00010000101
01100000101
00010011001
01100011001
00011101001
01101101001
0001001111
0110001111
0001110111
0110110111
```

We can separate the first part of the pattern, `0001`, from the second, `0000101`.  Each of the combinations above comes from rewriting `0001`, separately rewriting `0000101`, and glueing the two rewrites together.  There are 2 rewrites (including the original) for the left portion of the pattern, and 5 for the right, so we get 10 representations overall.

What makes this work is that any rewrite of the left half, `0001`, ends with either `01` or `10`, while any rewrite of the right half starts with `00` or `11`.  So there's no match for either `001` or `110` that overlaps the boundary.  We'll get this separation whenever we have two `1`s separated by an *even* number of zeros.

And this explains the small prime factors seen in Niklas's answer: in a randomly-chosen number, there will be many sequences of `0`s of even length, and each of those represents a point where we can split the computation.

The explanations are becoming a little convoluted, so here's some Python code.  I've verified that the results agree with Niklas's for all `n` up to `10**6`, and for a selection of randomly chosen large `n`.  It should have the same algorithmic complexity.

```py
def combinations(n):
    # Find Fibonacci numbers not exceeding n, along with their indices.
    # We don't need Fib(0) or Fib(1), so start at Fib(2).
    fibs = []
    a, b, index = 1, 2, 2
    while a <= n:
        fibs.append((index, a))
        a, b, index = b, a + b, index + 1

    # Compute greedy representation of n as a sum of Fibonacci numbers;
    # accumulate the indices of those numbers in indices.
    indices = []
    for index, fib in reversed(fibs):
        if n >= fib:
            n -= fib
            indices.append(index)
    indices = indices[::-1]

    # Compute the 'signature' of the number: the lengths of the pieces
    # of the form 00...01.
    signature = [i2 - i1 for i1, i2 in zip([-1] + indices[:-1], indices)]

    # Iterate to simultaneously compute total number of rewrites,
    # and the total number with the top bit set.
    total, top_set = 1, 1
    for l in signature:
        total, top_set = ((l + 2) // 2 * total - (l + 1) % 2 * top_set, total)

    # And return the grand total.
    return total
```

---

EDIT: Code substantially simplified.

---

EDIT 2: I just came across this answer again, and suspected that there was a more straightforward way.  Here's yet another code simplification, showing clearly that `O(log n)` operations are required.

```py
def combinations(n):
    """Number of ways to write n as a sum of positive
    Fibonacci numbers with distinct indices.
    """
    # Find Fibonacci numbers not exceeding n.
    fibs = []
    fib, next_fib = 0, 1
    while fib <= n:
        fibs.append(fib)
        fib, next_fib = next_fib, fib + next_fib

    # Compute greedy representation, most significant bit first.
    greedy = []
    for fib in reversed(fibs):
        greedy.append(fib <= n)
        if greedy[-1]:
            n -= fib

    # Iterate to compute number of rewrites.
    x, y, z = 1, 0, 0
    for bit in reversed(greedy):
        x, y, z = (0, y + z, x) if bit else (x + z, z, y)
    return y + z
```

Comment: Good observations. In fact, there are many interesting properties if you use the Fibonacci numbers as the base of a numeral system, for example the representation as a sum of distinct fibonacci numbers also exists and is unique if you demand that the indices of the chosen fibonacci numbers are at least 2 apart (which is basically what my answer is based on).

Comment: Hmm;  actually, the code can be substantially simplified, though that obscures the fact that the result is a product.  I'll update.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yep; that was why I included the `(unique)` hint.  There was a limit to how much information I was prepared to include in the answer.  (I used to teach this stuff, but I'd never encountered the question of how many representations there were before.)

Comment: There's also another generic way to count the number of ways to rearrange a representation, which works for a variety of numeral systems, for example [balanced ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary), quaternary etc. with negative digits (so that the representation is not unique): Let `f(i,j,k)` be the number of ways to represent the prefix `1..i` of a particular representation (for example the greedy one), where `j` is the carry to position `i` and `k` is the carry to position `i - 1`.

Comment: Obviously `f(i,j,k) = 0` if `max(j,k) > i`, so we have a bounded number of non-zero states. If the i-th digit of the greedy representation is `1`, we have `f(i,j,k) = f(i-1, k+j, j) + f(i-1, k+j+1, j+1)` and otherwise `f(i,j,k) = f(i-1, k+j-1, k+j-1) + f(i-1, k+j, j)`. Here it's easy to see the `O(log^2 n)` runtime, the way my code avoids the explicit state transition is kind of strange and I don't quite know why it works

Comment: Now that I think about it it's pretty easy to see that if `j + k > 3`, then `f(i,j,k) = 0`.

Comment: Using that we can even compute F(10^10000) pretty conveniently :)

Comment: Yes, it's pretty scary how fast this is.  The above code takes around 0.1 seconds to compute `F(10**10000)` on my machine.

Comment: GMP is one heck of a library

Comment: It sure is, but that's hardly relevant here. :-)  Python doesn't use GMP.  (Well, at least CPython doesn't.)

Comment: Haha, I confused it with Ruby :) Then it's probably just modern CPUs with SIMD that make addition so damn fast

Answer (score 1):

You can find the lexicographically largest 0/1 representation in Fibonacci-base by taking the largest Fibonacci number less than or equal your number, subtract that and then take the next largest Fibonacci number less than or equal to the remainder, etc. Then the question is how to find all other 0/1 representations in Fibonacci-base from the lexicographically largest one. I believe you can use the Fibonacci recurrence relation to do this. For example if your representation is 1100... then you can replace the 2nd largest Fib number in the representation with the sum of the next two, giving 1011.....If you recursively process the string this way from left to right repeatedly, either choosing to make the substitution or not whenever you can, and using dynamic programming to remember which representations you have already explored, I believe you will get all the representations, and in O(m log n) time where m is the total number of Fibonacci representations for your number n. I'll update if I find a definitive proof of that. Meanwhile you can check the conjecture for numbers up to about a million or so. If it checks out for all those cases, then it's almost certainly true in general.

Comment: Since there's no guarantee that the "next" largest number will part of a valid solution, I believe this approach is still exponential.

Answer (score 0):

One of naive possibilities in python (works up to 10^6 in reasonable time)

```
def nfibhelper(fibm1,fibm2,n):
    fib = fibm1 + fibm2
    if fib > n:
        return 0
    r=0
    if n == fib :
        r+=1
    return r + nfibhelper(fibm2,fib,n-fib) + nfibhelper(fibm2,fib,n)


def F(n):
    return nfibhelper(1,0,n) ##1 will be used twice as fib
```